# Get the sum of json objects categorically in python

Tags: python, json

I am working on a problem where I want to get the sum of JSON objects categorically in a hashmap. Here's my idea of what the hashmap should look like:

```
{name: totalScore}
```

here's my sample JSON data:

```
[
    {
        "name": "Hilary Carr",
        "submissions": [
            {
                "name": "Laudantium deleniti beatae fuga.",
                "date": "05/12/2021",
                "score": 37
            }
        ]
    },
{
        "name": "Frederick Williamson",
        "submissions": [
            {
                "name": "Expedita architecto voluptas autem veniam.",
                "date": "03/05/2009",
                "score": 47
            },
            {
                "name": "Animi facere excepturi.",
                "date": "01/02/2021",
                "score": 100
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Here's what I have tried

```
sums = {}
score = 0
for i in json_data:
    for j in i['submissions']:
        score += j['score']
    sums[i['name']] = sums.get(i['name'], 0) + score
```

and here's what I get:

```
{
    "Frederick Williamson": 184,
    "Hilary Carr": 37
}
```

But it should come out to be:

```
{
    "Frederick Williamson": 147,
    "Hilary Carr": 37
}
```

It might be a trivial mistake, but can you please help me with this.

Comment: You need to move this line ```score = 0``` after the first loop  ```for i in json_data:``` otherwise you use the old score value

Comment: @Nabil Cheers. Thanks for pointing my trivial mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use dict-comprehension to sum scores of different persons:

```py
lst = [
    {
        "name": "Hilary Carr",
        "submissions": [
            {
                "name": "Laudantium deleniti beatae fuga.",
                "date": "05/12/2021",
                "score": 37,
            }
        ],
    },
    {
        "name": "Frederick Williamson",
        "submissions": [
            {
                "name": "Expedita architecto voluptas autem veniam.",
                "date": "03/05/2009",
                "score": 47,
            },
            {
                "name": "Animi facere excepturi.",
                "date": "01/02/2021",
                "score": 100,
            },
        ],
    },
]

out = {d["name"]: sum(s["score"] for s in d["submissions"]) for d in lst}

print(out)
```

Prints:

```py
{'Hilary Carr': 37, 'Frederick Williamson': 147}
```